# How to obtain the original files, from undeleted encrypted files?

Tags: encryption, windows-10

in Windows 10, I have deleted a few files in an external hard disk, from folders that have the encryption activated (Properties/Advanced/Encrypt contents to secure data).
I easily undeleted those files (since I realized I needed them) but they are obviously totally scrambled.
Is there a way to 'apply' the encryption property to the containing folders, without scrambling them again? If I try to bring them in another encrypted folder, they are of course scrambled even more, although I hoped that it could someway recognize that the keys are the same, because I'm on the same machine...
Any idea, please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I clarify that I undeleted the files with a third party tool, that probably is not aware of the encryption.

Comment: I add that I tried for example with cipher, but there's no way to change the encryption attribute on a file ('E' or 'U'), so trying to decrypt a 'U' marked file has no effect... :-(

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about what kind of encryption it is? or At-least explain which process you follow to encrypt the files

Comment: What type of encryption algorithm was used? Also, Have you considered D:\ directory? It may seem silly to ask, but I've overlooked the option before to my own detriment.

Comment: Yes, I tried everything, with cipher. I cannot know what is the encryption algorithm, since I just applied it interactively in the properties of the folder.